# DP - Min cost climbing stairs

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I'm trying to solve Min cost - climbing stairs problem.

This is the link: https://leetcode.com/problems/min-cost-climbing-stairs/

I've written the recursive version of the solution and it worked for the sample test cases, and obviously it showed TLE for the rest cases.
Here's the recursive version:

```
int solve(int[] arr, int idx, int cost) {
        if(idx >= arr.length) return cost;
         
        return Math.min(solve(arr, idx + 1, cost + arr[idx]), 
                       solve(arr, idx + 2, cost + arr[idx]));
}
```

Now, the problem is when I'm trying to memoize it using 1-d array, I'm not getting correct answers for sample cases as well.

Here's the memoized version:

```
int[] t;
    Solution() {
        this.t = new int[1001];
    }
    
    public int minCostClimbingStairs(int[] arr) {
        int n = arr.length;
        Arrays.fill(t, -1);
        
        return Math.min(solve(arr, 0, 0), solve(arr, 1, 0));
    }
    
    int solve(int[] arr, int idx, int cost) {
        if(idx >= arr.length) return cost;
        
        if(t[idx] != -1) return t[idx];
        
        return t[idx] = Math.min(solve(arr, idx + 1, cost + arr[idx]), 
                       solve(arr, idx + 2, cost + arr[idx]));
    }
```

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance.

From a Noob in DP.

Comment: For this problem, if you do take DP approach right,  you don't need memo then.

Comment: @DanielHao What's the "DP approach right"?

Comment: You just need last 2 values, right? Do you like to take Python or JS solution?